# Delete multiple ROS parameters at once

Tags: rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to delete multiple ROS parameters at once using `rosparam delete` but the command-line only allows to delete the parameters one by one. Unfortunately, sometimes, when re-running a node some of the node state is preserved in the parameters, hence when I want to make sure the nodes start in initial, canonical state I want to clear multiple parameter values at once. I imagine something like

`rosparam delete '/my_node/*'`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31711/delete-multiple-ros-parameters-at-once/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2012-04-12

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the command line, you can delete it with:

```
rosparam delete /my_node
```

This should get rid of all parameters in your node's namespace. Alternatively, when using a launch file you can use clear_params (see [here](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node)):

```
<node name="foo" pkg="bar" type="baz" clear_params="true" />
```

This will get rid of all params in namespace `foo` before launching the node.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12